# Client side encryption Django

Tags: javascript, django, encryption, client-side-scripting

I just finished an app and, for safety reasons, I would like the content of some fields of the db to be readable only by the user. This involves **client side encryption** and I think that I found a decent [pure js implementation](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js).

Typically, I would go for an AES 256 CBC using parts of the user's password hash (client side computation) as **key** an **vi** (stored somehow) to feed the encrypt and decrypt functions.

*Here comes the thing*. The **decryption** is pretty straightforward. Spontaneously, I would call the function directly in the templates using the objects passed in context as inputs for my function. It would look like:

```
<div class=whatever_the_class>
    <script>
        decrypt_function({{ patient.first_name }}, key, vi) 
        decrypt_function({{ patient.last_name }}, key, vi)
    </script>
</div>
```

However, I am not sure how to deal with **encryption** in forms. I think that I need to bypass somehow the way my forms work (in this example *form_add*) to take the output of my encrypt function as data but I really do not know how/where to do it. In the widget section of my form? In the template?

Any thoughts? Any clean way to do it? (I am also interested in similar questions/posts/projects to get a clearer picture)

```
# template
<form id="add_patient" method="post" action="add-patient/"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form_add }}
        <input type="submit" value="Entrer">
</form>

# view
def index(request):
    try:
        user = request.user
        form_add = AddPatientForm()

        return render(request, 'jengu/index.html', {'form_add': form_add, 'form_record': form_record})
    except:
        return redirect('/')

# form
class AddPatientForm(forms.Form):
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Nom', max_length=40)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Prénom', max_length=40)
    birthday = forms.DateField(label='date de naissance',
    widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y',attrs={'placeholder': '31/03/1989'}),
    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y',])
```

Comment: If you're decrypting in the Django template then it's not client side encryption - I think you mean to pass the encrypted values back in the template and then use JavaScript. The server side should never see the keys for it to be true client side encryption (or I might be misinterpting it and you need to add a script tag to evaluate the js function)

Comment: ??? Nope. The template is sent to the client once the contextual variables are added to it. If I call a js function in the template, it is loaded and executed by the client's browser once it reaches it (the same way the css files in static are loaded client-side). It is not because the code appears on the template that it is executed server side. Or I am not sure what you meant

Comment: OK, I'll edit to add the script tags in order to avoid confusion. (I am not much of a "front man", so to speak)

Comment: The other thing that comes to mind is that storing "vi" as a cookie means that the browser will include it as part of every request it sends to the server which may not be desirable

Comment: isn't there a way to tweak it? I naively thought that a cookie was not necessarily sent with every request. Good point, I do not want this to be sent along (nor the key, for that matter). How would you proceed? A good way to store locally?

Comment: I'd suggest using local storage, or indexdb. However I'd be a little concerned about the permanence of all these solutions (including cookies) - I'd make sure your users had a way to backup the key